# Magento2 separting product info block

Tags: magento, magento2

What I need is - to move the Product Options block below the `addtocart` block.

In the template file

`Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/detail_layout.phtml`

the info is coming from

`echo  $block->getChildHtml('product.info') ?>`

`product.info` block holds the data both for `custom options` and `addtocart`

I am not able to locate which file holds this data, so that I can move or switch position.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to overrule the layout options which are set by the default `/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` file with your own theme. Add `after="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom"` to the product options block, like so:

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.